# gradient exposure from center to all directions

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have a picture, where there are underexposed parts in the outer areas. To achieve, that the outer are gradually more exposed, I would like to create a new exposure layer with a two-folded mask:

1. A selection of the frame areas, that are affected by the exposure (simply by a rectangular selection and inversion)
2. A gradient selection that over-exposes the area the more, the farther it is away from the center of the picture.

**Question**: How can I achieve the second part of the masking?

Comment: Please attach snapshots to clarify your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the adjustment layer exposure.

Add a layer mask to that adjustment layer.

Create a rectangle selection with the marquee tool. that is halfway between the underexposed and the properly exposed image.

[image: marquee selection]

Go to Select -> Refine Edge. Move the feather slider until you get a selection that will be the right amount of gradation.

Now fill your layer mask with black.

Note: I find it may just be easier to paint the layer mask with a low opacity brush rather than try to guess the feather amount.

Comment: +1 basically, a layer mask is a grayscale image that can be painted on. The grey values are used to decide how transparent the layer is at any given pixel. So the mask can be used to modulate the degree of exposure adjustment, which is basically super precise dodge &burn. For the particular question, the OP can also use the circular gradient tool, and there is no reason the OP cannot use multiple exposure adjust layers with different masks.